# Javascript object with shared name

Tags: javascript, object

So, I'm trying to create an object like:

```
var a = {
    b: "object_id",
    b: function(){ return c(this.b); }
}
var c = {
    "object_id": {
        foo: "bar"
    }
}
```

But it only registers the last value for the key 'b'. But I think I've seen something like this used before and it would really help me if I could call a.b().foo or if I just want ID a.b

Is there any way to make this happen or will I have to rename value and/or method?

Comment: Object keys are unique.  Always.

Comment: You will need to change the property name otherwise it won’t know what property of the object you are referring to.

Comment: `c` isn't a method, though... it's an object

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Object Getter/Setter notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

```
var o = {
  _b: 7,
  get b() { 
    return this._b + 1;
  },
}
```

That being the case, you CAN'T use the same object id, and should store the internal variable for b in a closure, if you need it to be totally private.